# How to use Maven with m2e?

Tags: maven-3, m2eclipse

I have the following lines which I want to execute

```
mvn dependency:sources
mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc
```

How can I use m2e in Eclipse to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Right-click on your project `pom.xml`
2. Choose `Run as` -> `Maven Build`
3. It will open up a pop-up
4. Type your goal in the `Goals:`

Or alternately, to set up a Eclipse `Run Configurations`:

1. Go to `Run` menu
2. Choose `Run Configurations` -> `Maven Build`
3. Double-click it to create a new `Maven Build Run` configuration:
4. Give your new configuration a name, specify your project root directory as its workspace
5. And set your goal and add parameters in the appropriate sections.

Answer (score 2):

Simply right-click on your project, then Maven > Download Sources (or Download Javadoc).

Generally, once you have the sources, downloading the javadoc is useless, as it shows up if you hover on methods in the Java editor.

Comment: Best solution of all.